# Excel VBA code doesn't paste data

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro (found on StackOverflow) that is intended to allow a user to select a workbook from their desktop and it copies all the information in column A of that sheet, to column A in the main workbook. However, the macro doesn't **paste** the data. It simply leaves the dotted line around the area it intends to paste in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()

Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If uploadfile = "False" Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A:A").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Load Barcodes").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You're pasting values so just set ranges to each other. Also, don't copy the entire column.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to say? Should I do something like this: `Range("A1:A100").value = Sheets("Load Barcodes").Range("A1:100").value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as posted should work, but as a learning guide here are a few tips:

- You don't need to `.Activate` the open workbook, the `Open` action
  already does that
- It's not needed for your `CurrentBook` either, simply specifying the source and destination in the `Copy` is sufficient
- @findwindow's point is to determine the last row containing your data and only copy/paste that range area, not the entire column
- Pay attention to your variable names, they can really help you keep clear where things are going

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()
    Dim uploadFilename As Variant
    Dim currentBook As Workbook
    Dim uploadBook As Workbook
    Dim barcodeSheet As Worksheet
    Dim uploadSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set currentBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set barcodeSheet = currentBook.Sheets("Load Barcodes")

    uploadFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                                   FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks,*.xlsx;*.xls", _
                                   Title:="Select Uploader file to be reviewed")
    If uploadFilename <> "False" Then
        Set uploadBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=uploadFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set uploadSheet = uploadBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = uploadSheet.Cells(uploadSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        uploadSheet.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1).Copy _
                     Destination:=barcodeSheet.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
        uploadBook.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions, my VBA is rough and any tips are extremely helpful. This code worked for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have quoted should work. The dotted lines appear around the cells that are copied (from the uploader workbook selected by the user) not the target range for the Paste Special operation.

The code does not specify the sheet from which to copy column A, so it will copy the first column of whichever sheet was avtice when the workbook was saved. Try specifying the sheet codename such as `Sheet1.Range("A:A")`.

Comment: Okay, I understand this better, thank you for the tip.